# How can I horiontally center my vertical progress bars inside their respective divs?

Tags: html, css

I am using materializecss as my framework to display some progress bars. They were originally horizontal but I used the CSS transform property to rotate them vertical. I noticed that the div class "progress progress-dashboard-full vertical" does not line up in the center of it's parent div class="col s3 m3 l3".

I don't really notice much on a full screen but if I go down to a smaller screen size the divs and progress bars don't center. Could someone explain what I need to do in order to have the progress bars spread out evenly and be centered inside the parent div?

```css
.vertical {
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg)translate(0px, -17px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg)translate(0px, -17px);
  transform: rotate(270deg)translate(0px, -17px);
  height: 3rem;
  width: 12rem !important;
  ;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  transform-origin: 40% 70%;
}

.vertical-determinate {
  height: 100% !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

.materialID-bars {
  background-color: #FAFF0D;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row m-b-0" style="">
  <div class="col s3 m3 l3 p-l-0 p-r-0">
    <div class="progress progress-dashboard-full vertical">
      <div class="determinate progress-dashboard-loaded vertical-determinate" style="width: 50%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s3 m3 l3 p-l-0 p-r-0" style="">
    <div class="progress progress-dashboard-full vertical">
      <div class="determinate progress-dashboard-loaded vertical-determinate" style="width: 50%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s3 m3 l3 p-l-0 p-r-0" style="">
    <div class="progress progress-dashboard-full vertical">
      <div class="determinate progress-supports-loaded vertical-determinate" style="width: 50%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s3 m3 l3 p-l-0 p-r-0" style="">
    <div class="progress progress-dashboard-full vertical">
      <div class="determinate progress-supports-loaded vertical-determinate" style="width: 50%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="materialID-bars" style="clear: both; position: relative; bottom: 4rem">316L Stainless</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this-- I added a style block for `.progress.vertical` at the bottom-- here I wiped out the existing margins, and then adjusted the translated distance to be half of the height.  I *think* this is looking close to what you're aiming at...

```css
.vertical {
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg)translate(0px, -17px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg)translate(0px, -17px);
  transform: rotate(270deg)translate(0px, -17px);
  height: 3rem;
  width: 12rem !important;
  ;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  transform-origin: 40% 70%;
}

.vertical-determinate {
  height: 100% !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

.materialID-bars {
  background-color: #FAFF0D;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.progress.vertical {
  margin: 0;
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg)translate(0px, -2px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg)translate(0px, -2px);
  transform: rotate(270deg)translate(0px, -2px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row m-b-0" style="">
  <div class="col s3 m3 l3 p-l-0 p-r-0">
    <div class="progress progress-dashboard-full vertical">
      <div class="determinate progress-dashboard-loaded vertical-determinate" style="width: 50%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s3 m3 l3 p-l-0 p-r-0" style="">
    <div class="progress progress-dashboard-full vertical">
      <div class="determinate progress-dashboard-loaded vertical-determinate" style="width: 50%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s3 m3 l3 p-l-0 p-r-0" style="">
    <div class="progress progress-dashboard-full vertical">
      <div class="determinate progress-supports-loaded vertical-determinate" style="width: 50%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s3 m3 l3 p-l-0 p-r-0" style="">
    <div class="progress progress-dashboard-full vertical">
      <div class="determinate progress-supports-loaded vertical-determinate" style="width: 50%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="materialID-bars" style="clear: both; position: relative; bottom: 4rem">316L Stainless</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, that actually solved a lot of my issues. I'm still having one more problem where if I change the width (which increased the bars vertically since it's flipped" the bars actually push right as they increase. However I noticed that if I changed the transform origin to "left" they stay in place and I can increase the width as much as I want. Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: Glad I could help!  Off the top of my head I'm not sure about the shifting issue.  It's hard to test increasing widths in the built-in SO snippets, but maybe you could create a JSFiddle and post a new question?  That way SO users can click out and manipulate the "viewport" in order to understand the issue better.  Just a though.